# How to get a link to a Google Translate translation?

Tags: google-translate, links

I was able in the past to do that, but I can't find how anymore.

Comment: Easily. Install Google translate app to your mobile device. Open web page in your mobile. Click  three dots in upper right corner of your browser - click Share -scroll until you find Google translate app. There you will have option to choose translate language and link above will be link on page with chosen translation which you can share.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

All I had to do is to click in the "Translate" button and the URL was updated.
The instant translation doesn't update the URL.

The URL format is:

```
http://translate.google.com/#origin_language_or_auto|destination_language|encoded_phrase
or
http://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&sl=auto&tl=destination_language&text=encoded_phrase
```

If you want to translate a webpage, use:

```
http://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&sl=auto&tl=destination_language&u=http://example.net
```

**destination_language** must be a language code, like **en** for English or **pt-BR** for Brazilian Portuguese. You can also set a value for **sl** (source language) instead of "auto".

Comment: Update these links to `https` to avoid browser security errors.

Comment: I have tried to use this answer, but failed: `https://translate.google.com/translate?js=n&sl=ja&tl=en&u=https://www.j-platpat.inpit.go.jp/web/all/top/BTmTopPage` - although the page translates fine when put into the url field manual. Am I missing a parameter?

Comment: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with URL https://translate.google.com/translate?... from frame with URL https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?... The frame attempting navigation of the top-level window is sandboxed, but the flag of 'allow-top-navigation' or 'allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation' is not set. Failed to set the 'href' property on 'Location': The current window does not have permission to navigate the target frame to https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?... at https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?...

Comment: What about [Bing Translate](https://www.bing.com/translator)?

Comment: If you receive the 'can't translate this page' error when using chrome, make sure that in language settings, the [option to translate pages](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/173424?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop) is enabled.   It is enabled by default, but I had turned it off in the past apparently.

Answer (score 13):

Just go on [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/) and paste the URL to translate in the left box. Select your target (and source) language and click on the resulting link in the right box.

You will be redirected to the translated website in the desired language. The URL can be shared with others to share the translated website.

Because the translation URLs are very long, I tend to shorten them with http://goo.gl/.

Comment: This no longer seems to work.

Answer (score 13):

Here's another alternative that works if you wanted to share the link on Facebook for instance:

/translate.google.com/#origin_language_or_auto|destination_language|encoded+phrase+connected+with+plus+symbols

Example
http://translate.google.com/#auto/en/С+днём+рождения!

This link, when clicked would take you to the Google Translate page, auto detect the language, and translate it from Russian into English.  The "+" symbols are needed between the words in the phrase to be translated to insure that Facebook includes the entire phrase in the link.

For your convenience, here's a list of language abbreviations used by Google Translate:

The following table contains a recent list of languages supported by Google Translate.

```
No. Language Name   Native Language Name    Code

1   Afrikaans       Afrikaans           af
2   Albanian        Shqip               sq
3   Arabic          عربي                ar
4   Armenian        Հայերէն             hy
5   Azerbaijani     آذربایجان دیلی      az
6   Basque          Euskara             eu
7   Belarusian      Беларуская          be
8   Bulgarian       Български           bg
9   Catalan         Català              ca
10  Chinese (Simp.) 中文简体                zh-CN
11  Chinese (Trad.) 中文繁體                zh-TW
12  Croatian        Hrvatski            hr
13  Czech           Čeština             cs
14  Danish          Dansk               da
15  Dutch           Nederlands          nl
16  English         English             en
17  Estonian        Eesti keel          et
18  Filipino        Filipino            tl
19  Finnish         Suomi               fi
20  French          Français            fr
21  Galician        Galego              gl
22  Georgian        ქართული             ka
23  German          Deutsch             de
24  Greek           Ελληνικά            el
25  Haitian Creole  Kreyòl ayisyen      ht
26  Hebrew          עברית               iw
27  Hindi           हिन्दी                  hi
28  Hungarian       Magyar              hu
29  Icelandic       Íslenska            is
30  Indonesian      Bahasa Indonesia    id
31  Irish           Gaeilge             ga
32  Italian         Italiano            it
33  Japanese        日本語             ja
34  Korean          한국어                 ko
35  Latvian         Latviešu            lv
36  Lithuanian      Lietuvių kalba      lt
37  Macedonian      Македонски          mk
38  Malay           Malay               ms
39  Maltese         Malti               mt
40  Norwegian       Norsk               no
41  Persian         فارسی               fa
42  Polish          Polski              pl
43  Portuguese      Português           pt
44  Romanian        Română              ro
45  Russian         Русский             ru
46  Serbian         Српски              sr
47  Slovak          Slovenčina          sk
48  Slovenian       Slovensko           sl
49  Spanish         Español             es
50  Swahili         Kiswahili           sw
51  Swedish         Svenska             sv
52  Thai            ไทย                 th
53  Turkish         Türkçe              tr
54  Ukrainian       Українська          uk
55  Urdu            اردو                ur
56  Vietnamese      Tiếng Việt          vi
57  Welsh           Cymraeg             cy
58  Yiddish         ייִדיש               yi
```